# Replace for loop with ES syntax

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to rewrite my loop for with ES syntax. I've tried to replace just one of loops but it's being called a few times. How can i use ES syntax to return a single value? The output should be undefined or a single value.

Input example:

```
[{"events": [{"type": "Change", "field_name": "123"}], "created_at": "2017-07-01"}, 
{"events": [{"type": "Change", "field_name": "456"}], "created_at": "2017-08-01"},
{"events": [{"type": "Change", "field_name": "789"}], "created_at": "2017-09-01"}]
```

And the function:

```
function extractAuditEventDate(data, field, type) {
    console.log(data)
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        const audit = data[i]

        // const event = audits.events.find(e => e.type === type && e.field_name === field)

        for (var j = 0; j < audit.events.length; j++) {
            const event = audit.events[j]

            if (event.type === type && event.field_name === field) {
                //console.log(audits.created_at)
                return audit.created_at
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If I `extractAuditEventDate` and pass parameters data as input exampple, '456' as fieldname and 'Change' as type, I expect to get '2018-07-01'

Comment: It's a bit unclear what behavior you're looking for. What do you expect the return value of the function to be? Why does ES6 syntax have to do with anything? Please be more specific.

Comment: moreover your field and type are undefined as per the input provided

Comment: I've updated the entire post

Comment: I would avoid to use for inside for..not sure how to implement use it using .forEach and find functions

Comment: Is there any particular reason you want to avoid nested loops?  That's usually the best way to handle nested arrays, and ES6 features don't change that.

Comment: No, just fancy! I want to look smarter and hype writing javascript! Why it's the best way to handle nested arrays?

Comment: @placplacboom The way you're currently doing it would technically be faster than using something like an `ES6` `array.forEach()`. Seems counter-productive to translate this to ES6? What you could start with is renaming your `var`'s to `const` and `let` and convert your entire `function () {}` to an arrow function ?

Comment: There's no ES6 syntax that replaces looping to search arrays. The only special ES6 syntax related to arrays is spreading and destructuring, which can replace loops when copying the array. But they don't apply to this question.

Answer (score 1):

There you go!

```js
const data = [{"events": [{"type": "Change", "field_name": "123"}], "created_at": "2017-07-01"}, 
{"events": [{"type": "Change", "field_name": "456"}], "created_at": "2017-08-01"},
{"events": [{"type": "Change", "field_name": "789"}], "created_at": "2017-09-01"}]

// returns false if can't find the result
const extractAuditEventDate = (data, field, type) => {
    let hit;
    try {
      hit = data.find((el) => el.events.find(
       (e) => (e.type === type && e.field_name === field)))['created_at'];   
    } catch(err) {
      hit = false;
    }
    return hit;
}

console.log(
  extractAuditEventDate(data, '456', 'Change'), // Found it
  extractAuditEventDate(data, '789536', 'Change'), // Not Found (false)
  extractAuditEventDate(data, '456', 'IWILLFAIL'), // Not Found (false)
  extractAuditEventDate(data, {}) // What are you doing (false)
);
```

Comment: there is just small issue if the item is not found

Comment: should the function return false if fails to search?

Comment: thee original function results in `undefined` when not found, so that was my guess

Comment: I added a workaround but i don't know if this is art or shit.

Answer (score 1):

Small alternative to handle cases when the item is not found :

```js
const data = [{"events": [{"type": "Change", "field_name": "123"}], "created_at": "2017-07-01"}, 
              {"events": [{"type": "Change", "field_name": "456"}], "created_at": "2017-08-01"},
              {"events": [{"type": "Change", "field_name": "789"}], "created_at": "2017-09-01"}]

const extractAuditEventDate = (data, field, type) => ({...
  data.find(audit => audit.events.some(event => 
    event.type === type && event.field_name === field))}).created_at   

console.log( extractAuditEventDate(data, '123', 'Change') )
console.log( extractAuditEventDate(data, '123', 'change') )
```

ES6 functional alternatives should be few times slower than your ES version, because of the overhead.

---

Faster and more readable alternative can be [`for...of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) loop (not supported in IE) :

```js
const data = [{"events": [{"type": "Change", "field_name": "123"}], "created_at": "2017-07-01"}, 
              {"events": [{"type": "Change", "field_name": "456"}], "created_at": "2017-08-01"},
              {"events": [{"type": "Change", "field_name": "789"}], "created_at": "2017-09-01"}]

function extractAuditEventDate(data, field, type) {
  for (let audit of data)
    for (let event of audit.events)
      if (event.type === type && event.field_name === field)
        return audit.created_at
}

console.log( extractAuditEventDate(data, '123', 'Change') )
console.log( extractAuditEventDate(data, '123', 'change') )
```

Answer (score -2):

Try on your dev console:

```
var j =  [{"events": [{"type": "Change", "field_name": "123"}], "created_at": "2018-07-01"}, 
{"events": [{"type": "Change", "field_name": "456"}], "created_at": "2017-08-01"},
{"events": [{"type": "Change", "field_name": "789"}], "created_at": "2017-09-01"}];

var date = '2018-07-01';
var fieldName = '123';
var type = 'Change';

j.find(c => c.created_at == date).events.find(event => event.type == type && event.field_name == fieldName)
```

Comment: Functions should not rely on data that is not passed into the function. date, fieldName and type should be parameters of the function. Doing this in a technical test would blow the job interview for you instantly.